# My Angular tag input matInput not working

Tags: html, angular

I using angular/material version 10.2.3 and angular version 10.1.4.
Here my code sample:

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Test Label:</mat-label>
  <input matInput>
</mat-form-field>
```

but its visual output isnt the same what i found on documentary

[image]

and mine:

[image]

Why is that?

Comment: Check the `console` if there is any error. Don't forget to import the dependencies.           `import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';`

Comment: theres no error on the console and i did import MatInputModule beforehand still it didnt work the way it supposed to be